# Giving proof of a complex numbers equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that $T=\frac{a-bi}{a+bi}$, prove that $\frac{1+T^2}{2T}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}$. I already have the proof of this equation, however the working is what stumps me.
Rewriting this gives us $\frac{1+(\frac{a+bi}{a+bi})^2}{\frac{2(a-bi)}{a+bi}}$, yes?
However the proof provided to me replaces the 1 in the previous equation with $(\frac{a+bi}{a+bi})^2$. What is the reasoning behind this? I know that a+bi over a+bi is obviously one, but why do we need to do it and in what other situations should I apply this? TIA

Comment: When adding fractions, you need a common denominator.  In the numerator, you have one fraction with denominator $(a+b\mathrm{i})^2$, so you need to rewrite $1$ to have the same denominator...

Comment: How on Earth did I not think of that... I've got my head buried way too deep in the sand. Thank you

Comment: Alternatively, if $T\in\mathbb C$ then $T^2-(T+\bar T)T+(T\bar T)=0$, an equation with real coefficients.

Comment: Appreciate your input Ihf, but I am an absolute novice when it comes to set theory. The question does mention that $a$ & $b$ are real constants, but thank you

Comment: Because you want $(x+y)^{2}+(x-y)^{2}=2x^{2}-2y^{2}$, just some algebra manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated:
$$\frac{1+\left(\frac{a+bi}{a+bi}\right)^2}{\frac{2(a-bi)}{a+bi}}=\frac{(a-bi)^2+(a+bi)^2}{(a+bi)^2}\cdot\frac{a+bi}{2\cdot(a-bi)}=\frac{a^2-b^2-2abi+a^2-b^2+2abi}{a+bi}\cdot\frac{1}{2(a-bi)}=\frac{2\cdot(a^2-b^2)}{2(a+bi)\cdot(a-bi)}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}$$